# Installing rpm packages and resolving dependencies on an embedded device

Tags: package-management, yum, rpm, embedded, remote

I got an embedded device with RPM on (no Yum). The way I install packages now is by downloading the proper .rpm file from rpmfind.net and running `rpm -i package.rpm`. This process repeats for every missing library until the program finally runs.
There must be a better way to do it.
Can I automatically solve the dependencies on my desktop computer, copy .rpm files on the embedded device and install everything with a command like `rpm -i *`?

Comment: Desktop computer - Ubuntu x86_64.

Comment: Embedded device - ARMv7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try new project MicroDNF https://github.com/rpm-software-management/microdnf This is just small binary and will resolve the dependecies and install them.